# Evaluate $\int_0^1 \frac{\log(1-z)\log(1-z^3)}{z^2}dz$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, logarithms, mobius-inversion

Integrals of the kind $$\int_0^1 \frac{\log(1-z)\log(1-z^n)}{z^2}dz$$ where $n\geq 1$ is an integer, arises from a natural way when one apply Möbius inversion to get identities realated to $\zeta(2)$ (see my appendix if there are no mistakes), but how

> **Question.** Can you state a closed form for $$\int_0^1 \frac{\log(1-z)\log(1-z^3)}{z^2}dz?$$
>
> I am asking for a detailed explanationabout how get the definite integral. **Many thanks.**

I don't know if the general integral was in the literature but my trials with Wolfram Alpha, seems that is very difficult to get particular cases. See this

> **Example.** Other case of the indefinite integral, for example $n=5$ also is provided by [Wolfram Alpha online calculator](https://www.wolframalpha.com) when one type
>
> integrate (log(1-x)log(1-x^5))/x^2 dx

---

My idea was multiply both formulas of the first paragraph in **page 77 from:**

Benito, Navas, Varona, *Möbius inversion from the point of view of flows*, Proceedings of the Segundas Jornadas de Teoría de Números, Biblioteca de la Revista Matemática Iberoamericana (2008),

then integrating one gets $$\zeta(2)=\int_0^1\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{z^{n-1}}{n}dz=\int_0^1 \left(\frac{\log(1-z)}{z^2}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\mu(n)}{n}\log(1-z^n)\right)dz.$$ Here as you see $\zeta(s)$ is the Riemann's Zeta function and $\mu(n)$ is the Möbius function. And now from there one more time by absolute convergence, I've asked myself what's about these coefficients

$$a_n=\int_0^1 \frac{\log(1-z)\log(1-z^n)}{z^2}dz,$$ that for integers $n\geq 1$ satisfy $$\zeta(2)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\mu(n)}{n}a_n.$$

Comment: The required closed form is

$$
\frac{1}{6} \left(\left(-3-3 i \sqrt{3}\right) \text{Li}_2\left(\frac{1}{1+\sqrt[3]{-1}}\right)+3 \left(\sqrt{3}+i\right) i \text{Li}_2\left(\frac{1}{6} \left(3+i \sqrt{3}\right)\right)+2 \pi ^2-3 \log ^2(3)\right)
$$

Comment: Very nice @tired , but I don't know how get the indefinite integral, case $n=3$ and/or your definite integral. Many thanks for your attention and answer.

Comment: the keyideas are the following 

$\log(1+z^3)=\sum_i\log(1-\omega_i z)$

where $\omega_i $ are definded through the condition $1-z^3=0$

then we are left with integrals of the type

$$
\int_0^1\frac{\log(1-z)\log(1-\omega_i z)}{z^2}dz
$$

now we integrate  by parts:

$$
\int_0^1\left(-\frac{\log (1-z)}{z}+\log (1-z)+\log (z)\right)\frac{1}{1-\omega_i z}
$$

the resulting integrals can be now brought straightforwardly into a form which contains logartihms and dilogarithms

Comment: this idea also works also for powers $z^n$ in the second log of the original integral

Comment: As I said your formula and idea is very nice, thanks @tired